# Is it possible to export a simple Numbers spreadsheet while being dynamic?

Tags: ios, numbers, iwork

I have a few Numbers Spreadsheet that I use to keep track of my budget over the weeks/months but its only accessible in Numbers, which is fine Until I am at work where we use windows.

My only recourse there is my old iPhone runs Numbers slowly. I feel my phone works with PDF quickly.

Is it possible to export spreadsheet as a PDF document and still retain the automatic calculations of the spreadsheet and not just be a standard table?

Comment: Do you have an Apple ID / Cloud account?

Answer (score 1):

No, PDF exports of a numbers file become static and can no longer be edited as a spreadsheet. You must use the Numbers program (or an equivalent like Excel) to achieve the dynamic features of spreadsheets.

Comment: I might add, if numbers is slow, it’s almost always lots of formatting and formulas that loop on other formulas. Cleaning the spreadsheet might be faster than looking for an alternate spreadsheet app.

Answer (score 1):

There are web versions of the iWork applications, including Numbers, available in the [iCloud.com](http://icloud.com/) web portal (called iWork for iCloud).

These work in Windows as well, the only thing required is a supported Windows web browser.

Browser requirements for iWork for iCloud below (from https://www.apple.com/iwork/)

> iWork for iCloud works with Safari 9 or later, Chrome 50 or later, and
>   Internet Explorer 11 or later.

There is no need to export your Numbers document into a different format. If you save your Numbers spreadsheet document to your iCloud Drive on your Mac/iOS device, it will be available and editable in the web version. The edits you make in the web version of Numbers will then sync to your Mac/iOS device and vice versa.

This requires a free Apple ID / iCloud account. If you already set one up on your Mac or iOS device, you just use the credentials to login on the iCloud.com web portal.

Otherwise, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204174 for more info about setting up iCloud.com web access.